# media.play() not working with local paths

Tags: cordova

my folder structure is like below

```
www
  - index.html
  - ring
     - ring1.mp3
     - ring2.mp3
  - js
     - index.js
```

I have cordova media plugin installed and I am trying below paths to play video

```
  /android/assets/www/ring/ring1.mp3
  /android/asset/www/ring/ring1.mp3
  ring/ring1.mp3
  ./ring/ring1.mp3
```

like below

```
 var ringTone = new Media("/android/asset/www/ring/ring1.mp3",
    // success callback
    function () { 
        alert("playAudio():Audio Success"); 
    },
    // error callback
    function (err) { 
        alert("playAudio():Audio Error: " + JSON.stringify(err)); 
    }
 );
```

I am recieving error code 1 in error callback. How can I fix this issue.

**Edit**
 I have tried below one too

```
"/android_asset/www/ring/ring1.mp3"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue but adding file to path like below

```
 file:///android/assets/www/ring/ring1.mp3
```

Hope this is very helpful for someone...

Comment: Finally I got it working by adding the file access plugin with

cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file

Hope it helps